# Weird extra \b in front of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Xcode 6.1.1. Objective C.

I use the following code to get a `NSDictionary` before transform into `JSON` later on. During the breakpoint right after this line, I got the weird **extra** '\b' before the string 'dataTypeValue', which I tried with other strings gives me the same extra bit in the front. Anyone any ideas?

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:deviceInfoKey,deviceInfoData,dataTypeKey,actualData, nil]
                                                           forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"deviceInfoKey",@"deviceInfoData",@"dataTypeKey",@"dataTypeValue", nil]];
```

[image: @"\bdataTypeValue"]

Comment: Should be your own bug I think. I try the same code you provide with no issue.

Comment: That hidden character is probably coming from your code.  In Xcode, select "Editor -> Show Invisibles" from the menu to see any hidden control characters.  If necessary, try simply re-typing the line.

Comment: Do note that the debugger variable display is notorious for displaying bogus data.